# Printf and regex to format Java output

Tags: java, regex

I need to use printf to print data from a text file (the HashMap map is already populated, the Account values aren't null, everything is fine). But how do I use regex to not only maintain the even spacing of 20 spaces between my columns, but also round the last column, "Balance," to only 1 decimal point? I've looked at similar threads, but those formatting rules either threw errors or just had no effect. I tried using "%20s %20s %20s %20s.1f \n" for the first argument, but I ended up with this:

```
              ID           First Name            Last Name              Balance.1f 
            107H          Alessandro                Good             6058.14
            110K               Kolby                Cain              8628.4
            100A              Matias                Kane              290.99
            103D               Macie               House              631.12
            108I               Allan              Turner              914.89
            106G               Nancy               Avery             5201.38
            105F               Semaj               Olsen              344.63
            109J              Wilson              Hudson              771.65
            102C               Alana              Farmer              2004.5
            101B           Johnathan             Burgess              457.35
            104E              Andres              Rivers             3487.87
```

The total balance in all the accounts is: $28790.92

So it apparently only worked for a few of the data points?

Here's my code:

```
public void printData() {
        System.out.printf("%20s %20s %20s %20s%.1f \n", "ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Balance");
        for(Account a : map.keySet()) {
            // could do a.getID(), but rather get value from ArrayList
            ArrayList<String> myList = map.get(a); // retrieve the VALUE (ArrayList) using the key (Account a)
            for(String s : myList) {
                System.out.printf("%20s", s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your output supposed to be? Your **unintended** output is clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the decimals on each row under the column "balance" are simply being printed as the strings they are. The `%.1f` in the first line is only being used for the header row as formatting for a 5th argument it isn't receiving, and is not being applied to each following row.
Try this:

```
System.out.printf("%20s %20s %20s %20s\n", "ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Balance");
for(Account a : map.keySet()) {
    ArrayList<String> myList = map.get(a);

    //print the first 3 columns as strings
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.size()-1; i++) {
        String s = myList.get(i);
        System.out.printf("%20s", s);
    }

    //print the last column as a decimal rounded to 1 place after the decimal
    float balance = Float.parseFloat(myList.get(myList.size()-1));
    System.out.printf("%20s%.1f", "", balance);

    System.out.println();
}
```